# Redux: should I put component specific actions into global actions.js and pass down from the top?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Let's say I have the following component tree (Omitting the `mapStateToProps` and `mapActionToProps` syntax):

```
<Component_A set_data={set_data}>
  <Component_B set_data={set_data}>
    <Component_C set_data={set_data}>
    </Component_C>
  </Component_B>
</Component_A>
```

And action like `fetch_component_c_data` for `Component C`, knowing this action is not suitable for `Component A` and `Component B`, is it anti-pattern to leave it inside `Component C`? Or I should put this action into `actions.js` and pass it down?

And what if the `fetch_component_c_data` action that calls `set_data`:

```
fetch_component_c_data = () => {
    ...
    this.props.set_data(data);
}
```

does it become a requirement to be put inside `action.js`?

Comment: If you're using `connect` (it sounds like you are) you don't have to "pass anything down". You connect up Component C to your Redux store, import your action, and dispatch it from within the component.

Comment: True that, putting the `passing down from the top` aside, is it anti-pattern to leave that action in component c?